# Zookeeper Distributed system Design

Tags: distributed, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, hazelcast

I have an interesting distributed systems problem and not sure if zookeeper will fix this. In my enterprise application there are two applications integrated through REST/Web services - say North and South applications. North has multiple instances created and pooled for South interaction. North instance is a REST client which invoke REST APIs exposed by South , and South also generates lot of events which North instance subscribes and processes. North is computationally heavy and writes the data into a shared in-memory datastore like Hazelcast. and have many associated applications connected to it for processing the response received from South. For this reason North instances are split into distributed systems. In case of load (especially events from South) additional North instances are created (is there any framework who will take care of this). I would like to know if I have say a pool of nodes, can I split the North instances across these nodes and then use Zookeper for HA, Fault tolerence and synchronizations.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using Hazelcast for everything? Fault tolerance and synchronization are its key features.